# Python - finding complement of 2 lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, compare, complement

I'm looking for a method that would allow me to check what elements are missing when comparing 2 lists. A lot like in this thread but I want to write this in NumPy Python.

[Complement of Two Lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939404/complement-of-two-lists)

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
A = np.array([2,5,6,9])

def listComplementElements(list1, list2):

    storeResults = []

    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:

            if i != j:
                #write to storeResults if 2 numbers are different
                storeResults.append(i)
            else:
                #if numebrs are equal break out of the loop
                break

    return storeResults            

result = listComplementElements(numbers, A)
print(result) #expected result [1,3,4,7,8]
```

At the moment the output looks like this: [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Prune, that's an interesting duplicate choice, might I suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273686/create-a-complement-of-list-preserving-duplicate-values or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference

Comment: @NickA: much better; thanks.  I added it to the list of dups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you were going for:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
A = np.array([2, 5, 6, 9])

def listComplementElements(list1, list2):
    storeResults = []

    for num in list1:
        if num not in list2: # this will essentially iterate your list behind the scenes
            storeResults.append(num)

    return storeResults

result = listComplementElements(numbers, A)
print(result) #expected result [1,3,4,7,8]
```

Prints:

> [1, 3, 4, 7, 8]

You should only have one loop and then say `if not in` to evaluate the relationship with the second list. Otherwise you will loop unnecessarily and like you saw, it will output the result many times! Furthermore, using operators like `is in` or `not in` makes your code more readable than trying to comprehend many nested loops :)

Answer (score 12):

This will give you the complement of the two arrays:

```
list(set(numbers) - set(A))
```

```
[1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

If you have duplicate values that you want to preserve, you can use the following:

```
from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter(numbers)
c2 = Counter(A)

diff = c1 - c2
print(list(diff.elements()))
```

Comment: That is true. A different method would be required if you want to preserve duplicate values. I have updated my answer to include one.